# notice undefined constant assumed MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code which was just working well but after installing the new wamp server in my new mini compaq laptop? I get errors:

```
$sno=mysql_result($result,$m,"sno");
$name=mysql_resul($result,$m,"name");
$location=mysql_result($result,$m,"location");
$sector=mysql_result($result,$m,"sector");
$status=mysql_result($result,$m,"status");*/?>
<table width="320" border="0"cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <strong>   <td width="194"><strong><span class="style16"><font face="Lucida Console, Lucida Sans Unicode">PV NO:</font></span></strong></td>
    <td width="110" nowrap><span class="style16"><strong><?PHP echo "$_POST[pvno]";?></strong></span></td></strong>  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width="194"><span class="style16"><strong><font face="Lucida Console, Lucida Sans Unicode">SNO</font></strong></span></td>
    <td width="110" nowrap><span class="style16"><?PHP echo ''.$sno.''; ?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="style16"><strong><font face="Lucida Console, Lucida Sans Unicode">PROJECT NAME </font></strong></span></td>
    <td nowrap><span class="style16"><strong><?PHP echo $name;?></strong></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="style16"><strong>SECTOR</strong></span></td>
    <td nowrap><span class="style16"><?PHP echo $sector;?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="style16"><strong>CONTRACTOR</strong></span></td>
    <td nowrap><span class="style16"><?PHP echo $contractor;?></span></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><span class="style16"><strong>CONTACTS</strong></span></td>
    <td nowrap><span class="style16"><?PHP echo $contact;?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="style16"><strong>LOCATION</strong></span></td>
    <td nowrap><span class="style16"><?PHP echo $location;?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="style16"><strong>STATUS</strong></span></td>
    <td nowrap><span class="style16"><?PHP echo $status; ?></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The output error I get due to this is:

```
PV NO:  AGRI008
SNO     
Notice: Undefined variable: sno in C:\wamp\www\cdf\new pro\pvsearch.php on line 162
PROJECT NAME    
Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\wamp\www\cdf\new pro\pvsearch.php on line 166
SECTOR  
Notice: Undefined variable: sector in C:\wamp\www\cdf\new pro\pvsearch.php on line 170
CONTRACTOR  
Notice: Undefined variable: contractor in C:\wamp\www\cdf\new pro\pvsearch.php on line 174
CONTACTS    
Notice: Undefined variable: contact in C:\wamp\www\cdf\new pro\pvsearch.php on line 178
LOCATION    
Notice: Undefined variable: location in C:\wamp\www\cdf\new pro\pvsearch.php on line 182
STATUS  
Notice: Undefined variable: status in C:\wamp\www\cdf\new pro\pvsearch.php on line 186
```

any help please appreciated enter code here

Comment: Seems like the variables you are using don't exist. Where are those line numbers located in the file? Also you don't need to do `<?PHP echo ''.$sno.''; ?>` just echo it out `<?php echo $sno; ?>

Comment: And you have no opening PHP tag. And seem to have a closing comment tag in the 5th line of code `$status=myslq_result($result,$m,"status");*/?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?PHP echo "$_POST[pvno]";?>
```

`pvno` is not within quotes, thus its treated as a constant, but the constant doesn't exists (thats exactly what the notice tries to tell you)

use this instead

```
<?PHP echo $_POST['pvno'];?>
```

There is no reason for the double quotes around the variable.

Additional

```
<?PHP echo ''.$sno.''; ?>
```

Quotes useless here to

```
<?PHP echo $sno; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

in you're code i see `);*/?>`, witch means that the whole php block at the top is comented out so there are no variables to print out ( becouse they are never initialized ) .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code is commented-out, so it will be ignored. Get an editor with syntax highlighting which will make it easier for you to read source-code and to locate commented-out code fragments.

See this line:

```
$status=myslq_result($result,$m,"status");*/?>
                                          ^^ end of a multi-line comment
```

A warning about an undefined variable just means that the variable has not been initialized so far.